# C# parsing and arrays

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a program that parses some data, and somehow I'm not receiving what I need.

I have data in a file in the following order:

```
1111
username
email@email.com
IMAGE01: http://www.1234567890.net/image/cc_141019050341.png
```

So I made an array named "lines" with one data per line of text in the file, and then:

```
    this.videoId = lines[0];
    this.clientUser = lines[1];
    this.clientEmail = lines[2];

    this.textLines = new List<string>();
    this.imageLines = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    for (int i = 3; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("IMAGE"))
        {
            int imgNumber = Int32.Parse(
                    lines[i].Substring(Math.Max(0, lines[i].Length - 10), 2)
                );
            this.imageLines.Add(imgNumber, lines[i].Substring(Math.Max(0, lines[i].Length - 7)));
        }
        else
        {
            this.textLines.Add(lines[i]);
        }
    }
```

Then I put each parsed data into a different .txt file:

```
    using (StreamWriter emailTxt = new StreamWriter(@"txt/" + "user_email.txt"))
    {
        emailTxt.Write(nek.clientEmail);
    }

    using (StreamWriter userTxt = new StreamWriter(@"txt/" + "user_data.txt"))
    {
        userTxt.Write(nek.clientUser + Environment.NewLine + unixTime);
    }

    using (StreamWriter imageTxt = new StreamWriter(@"txt/" + "user_images.txt"))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kp in nek.imageLines)
        {
                imageTxt.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}: {1}", kp.Key, kp.Value));
        }
    }
```

But, somehow I'm retrieving all data good, except imageTxt which should be:

```
http://www.1234567890.net/image/cc_141019050341.png
```

I'm receiving:

```
05: 341.png
```

Any ideas why? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

your substrings are hitting cc_141019050341.png

```
cc_141019(first one extracts this 05)0(second one extracts this 341.png )
```

I would suggest you use regex to extract the parts you want

something like

```
IMAGE(?<num>\d+).*?:\s(?<url>.*)
```

you can use it in your code like

```
var match = new Regex(@"IMAGE(?<num>\d+).*?:\s(?<url>.*)").Match(line[i]]);
if (match.Success)
{
    var url = match.Groups["url"];
    var strNum = match.Groups["num"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, please check your email.